# Algorithm to get shortest path from node to itself -- Adjacency Matrix -- Java

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

[image: digraph]

[image: digraph]

```
public int dijkstra(){
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[gSize];

    int src = 1;
    int dest = 1;
    int[] distance = new int[5];
    int[] part = new int[5];
    int min;
    int nextNode = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = false;
        part[i] = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if(arr[i][j] == -1)
                arr[i][j] = 999; //gives it a high value to ignore
    }

    distance = arr[src];
    distance[src] = 0;

    visited[src] = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        min = 999;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if(min > distance[j] && visited[j] != true)
            {
                min = distance[j];
                nextNode = j;
            }

        visited[nextNode] = true;

        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            if(visited[k] != true)
                if(min + arr[nextNode][k] < distance[k])
                {
                    distance[k] = min + arr[nextNode][k];
                    part[k] = nextNode;
                }
    }
    return distance[dest];
}
```

This Dijkstra algorithm works as it is supposed to. However, it works only from vertex 'x' to vertex 'y'. I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to find the shortest path from vertex 'x' to vertex 'x'.

For example:

From B to B the shortest path should return 9 (B -> C -> E -> B). Am I taking a wrong approach by thinking that Dijkstra's algorithm can solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search the shortest path starting from nodes adjacent to x and finishing to the node x.

The shortest path will be the shortest sum of path length from x to an adjacent node plus the shortest path length from this adjacent node to x.

Basically in pseudocode:

```
// Note: The function neighbors(x) returns the list of neighbors of node x
// The function distance(x, y) returns distance between node x and y
// applying dijkstra algorithm

shortestDistance = 0;
for (Node neighbor : neighbors(x)) {
   currentDistance = distance(x, neighbor) + distance(neighbor, x);
   shortestDistance = min(currentDistance, shortestDistance);
}
return shortestDistance;
```

Comment: The only issue I forsee with this is that you would need to remove the direct link from your neighbor node and your starting node. Otherwise, you will always end up with 2 * the shortest length.

Comment: It depends if the graph is directed or not. If it is not a direct graph the shortest path is exactly 2 times the distance to the closest node. In both cases this solution works

Comment: Amazing... thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of this. My graph is a directed graph so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Run Dijkstra for each starting node to compute all pair shortest paths. Then you could compute self-shortest paths by going over adjacent nodes and adding this edge weight .In some cases shortest path would be infinity depending upon in-degree of a node.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tricky way to find shortest path from one node to itself for
directed graph with nonnegative weight, separate that node(say s) into two nodes s and s',the extra one s' is considered as a virtual one, build bidirected edges with the same weight if s has self loop, and also copy all edges which involve s for s', i.e. replace s with s'. Then the problem becomes to find the shortest path from s' to s. You only need to modify the Dijkstra's algorithm a little bit to implement this idea. just change the initialization. instead of setting up d[s]=0 and all others be infinity, set d[u] = w(s,u) for each adjacent node of s.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest path between two nodes in a grid can be described by the `Manhattan distance`

> Manhattan distance:
>   *The distance between two points in a grid based on a strictly
>   horizontal and/or vertical path (that is, along the grid lines), as
>   opposed to the diagonal or "as the crow flies" distance. The Manhattan
>   distance is the simple sum of the horizontal and vertical components,
>   whereas the diagonal distance might be computed by applying the
>   Pythagorean theorem.*
>   [Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)

Now if you wish to apply this to finding the shortest path you should read up on [`Heuristics`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) and more specifically the  [`A* Algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Perhaps this question and anwser might be of use to you: [A* Algorithm with Manhattan Distance Heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189211/a-algorithm-with-manhattan-distance-heuristic)